# Something a little different with angular and asp mvc - emailing from modal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I'm trying to do something a little different and so I was hoping you'd work with me.  My goal is an angular single page app within an asp mvc application.  I have my reasons for this, but one is that I like some benefits of both.  So my question is this.  Is it possible to use the webmail helper from within an angular modal.

Here is some of my code.  I felt like I was close, but now I'm not sure how it's interacting with my controller.

Email Controller - ASP

```
public class EmailController : Controller

{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

public ViewResult Index()
{
    int hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
    ViewBag.Greeting = hour < 12 ? "Good Morning" : "Good Afternoon";
    return View();
}

[HttpGet]
public ViewResult RequestForm()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ViewResult RequestForm(EmailRequest emailrequest)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // TODO: Email response to the party organizer 
        return View("Thanks", emailrequest);
    }
    else
    {
        // there is a validation error
        return View();
    }

}
```

Angular modal

```
<div class="modal" ng-show="isEmailPopupVisible">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="closeEmailPopup()">×</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "text", placeholder = "Enter your Name" }, })
            <br />
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "text", placeholder = "Enter Your Email" }, })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "text", placeholder = "Enter Phone Number" }, })
            <p>
                Will you attend?
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.WillAttend, new[] {
                new SelectListItem() {Text = "Yes, I'll be there",
                Value = bool.TrueString},
                new SelectListItem() {Text = "No, I can't come",
                Value = bool.FalseString}
                }, "Choose an option")
            </p>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send Email" />
        }
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">

          @* Issue with submit, not sure how to register thanks page and webmail logic.  *@

            <a href="#" class="btn btn" ng-click="closeEmailPopup()">Close</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

ASP model

```
public class EmailRequest
{

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your email address")]
    [RegularExpression(".+\\@.+\\..+",
        ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your phone number")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please specify whether you'll attend")]
    public bool? WillAttend { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks-cshtml

```
@model Project.Models.EmailRequest

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Thanks</title>
</head>
<body>
    @{
        try
        {
            WebMail.SmtpServer = "myserver";
            WebMail.SmtpPort = myport;
            WebMail.EnableSsl = false;
            WebMail.UserName = "myemail";
            WebMail.Password = "mypass";
            WebMail.From = "myemail";

            WebMail.Send("myemail", "Request Notification",
                Model.Name + " is " + ((Model.WillAttend ?? false) ? "" : "not")
                + "attending");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            @:<b>Sorry - we couldn't send the email to confirm your RSVP. </b>
    }
    }
    <div>
        <h1>Thank you, @Model.Name!</h1>
        @if (Model.WillAttend == true)
        {
            @:I'ts great that you're coming.  The drinks are already in the fridge!
      }
        else
        {
            @:Sorry to hear that you can't make it, but thanks for letting us know.
      }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I currently have the webmail smtp setting, etc in a "thanks.cshtml" page, but that seems to be with the standard asp mvc way of using the controller. I really don't know if I've shown you all enough to make sense of my goals, but is there a way to submit from the modal to my webmail settings without including the settings in the modal(users could see source).

Is this all a horrible idea, or am I somewhat close at something that is hopefully possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `WebMail` code in `Thanks.cshtml` should be in your controller instead.  It's a little hard to tell what your question is, how do you want the flow to happen in the future, do you want the 'thank you' to appear in the same modal where the form is?  I would make an AJAX call to send the mail and return success, it could even return the HTML from the view that you could replace in your modal if you wished...

Comment: I apologize, I knew I was putting too much in my question.  I'm basically trying to send an email from an angular modal from within an asp.net mvc project.  The logic I have above works outside of the modal, but I'm not sure how to adjust what I have with what I want.  I'm relatively new to many aspects of this, so this is probably adding to the issues.  Thank you for your help though.